# USB OTG flash drive as internal storage?

Tags: applications, usb-on-the-go

I happen to have a USB and an OTG that I got from a friend and I'm now low on storage due to apps size increasing because of updates.... SD cards costs a fortune in my place so I don't plan on buying one....

But is it possible to use USB Flashdrive as internal storage so I can move my apps to it?

Comment: Formatting an external OTG drive as internal is a very bad idea as you would not be able to remove this drive afterwards. Therefore you would have to leave the OTG drive attached forever. This also means that you would not be able to USB for charging (only if you would shut-down the device and charge it off state).

Comment: okay lets just say not really as internal but just to work like an sd card, or are they the same thing as u mentioned?

Comment: because of the physical unhandy situation guess there is some software limitation preventing this already, so only using as external storage is allowed